# In Azure logic App how to do load balance between two logic app using load balancer

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

If two logic apps are there in two different regions and I want to do load balancing between these two how to do this.

Through some source, I got to know that it is possible through API management but they have not mentioned how to do this.

So, how to do load balancing between two logic apps?

Answer (score 0):

Well...why do you want to do this?  "Load Balancing" especially with LogicApps is fundamentally different on Azure than on-premise or self hosted.  It's not wrong, just different ;)

What they were probably referring to was [Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview) which appears as a Networking Service, not APIM.

This, you can use to distribute requests as you would with traditional load balancers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to load balance across regions I would look into Azure Traffic Manager.  Traffic Manager is a DNS load balancer that sits outside/above Azure regions and allows you to have traffic balanced based on various performance profiles (i.e. Weighted, Performance, etc.)

High Level / General steps are:

- Setup Logic Apps in 2 Regions
- Create and register public dns domain for the logic apps - apps.foo.com (done outside Azure typically)
- Point your DNS record for apps.foo.com to Azure Traffic Manager
- Add endpoints to Azure Traffic Manager for Logic App in Region 1 and Logic App in Region 2 and setup your traffic manager profile

Calls to the Logic App start with the custom DNS domain get routed to ATM which then distributes to the regions based on your configured profile.